# How to interpret the phrase "t’en a fait voir à toi"?

Tags: expressions

> Hé ! On dirait qu'Alina **t’en a fait voir à toi** aussi. Tiens, prends-ça s’il te plaît, c’est de ma part.

I just heard this in conversation. Given what we were talking about, I wonder if "de toutes les couleurs" is dropped here or I'm dealing with a completely different expression:

> Hé ! On dirait qu'Alina t’en a fait voir **(de toutes les couleurs)** à toi aussi. Tiens, prends-ça s’il te plaît, c’est de ma part.

If I'm on the right track, is it common to leave the part "de toutes les couleurs" out like this?

Comment: Yes it is common. But without any context we can't be sure of the exact meaning of this sentence. It could have multiple meanings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En fait, c'est bien le même sens que "en faire voir de toutes les couleurs", mais ce n'est pas forcément parce que les "couleurs" ou les "vertes et les pas mûres" auraient été omises...

Il y a toute une famille d'expressions plus ou moins consacrées par l'usage, la plus simple étant "en faire voir", mais admettant aussi (cf. [dictionnaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voir)) :

> En faire voir de belles
>
> En faire voir de pires
>
> En faire voir de joyeuses
>
> En faire voir de drôles

Etc.

On peut imaginer plutôt (je ne sais pas si c'est étymologiquement correct mais aujourd'hui c'est à peu près la réalité) que l'expression "en faire voir" admette de se faire embellir par à peu près n'importe quel adjectif au goût de l'auteur.

La question reste ouverte de savoir ce à quoi "en" se réfère dans toutes ces expressions... tout au moins il doit s'agir d'un nom de genre féminin, mais à mon sens l'incertitude sur ce point fait partie du piquant de l'expression.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right, both looks correct and are perfectly understandable.

> Hé ! On dirait qu'Alina **t’en a fait voir à toi** aussi. Tiens,
>   prends-ça s’il te plaît, c’est de ma part.

Is more a shortcut of:

> Hé ! On dirait qu'Alina t’en a fait voir **(de toutes les couleurs)** à toi aussi. Tiens, prends-ça s’il te plaît, c’est de ma part.

As a [definition](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/19646/en-voir-de-toutes-les-couleurs/) of *en voir de toutes les couleurs* you have:

> Subir, endurer diverses épreuves. Traduction anglais : **She gave us a hard time !**.

As an alternative, you also can use "**Donner du fil à retordre**"

> Causer du souci à quelqu'un.

Comment: And the very similar *en voir des vertes et des pas mûres* too.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote "Given what we were talking about" so I guess you know about it but without clear context, we shouldn't rule out the fact the expression might have been genuine.

> *On dirait qu'Alina t’en a fait voir à toi aussi.*

which might translate to something like:

> It looks like Alina showed some of them to you too.

or

> It looks like Alina also showed you some of them.

Comment: Well I disagree here "*It looks like Alina showed some of them to you too.*" Isn't even correct english no matter the context.

Comment: (off-topic question about "à toi aussi") Whether meant literally or part of a figure of speech, I imagine that "à toi" is referring to the same "t'" in "t'en" in order to make it clear that Alina gave a hard time (or showed something) to more than one person (including the speaker). Would the "aussi" alone (without the "à toi") also mean this (albeit, less emphatically) or could "aussi" alone be ambiguous (especially if meant literally)   (i.e., perhaps Alina  showed more than one thing but not necessarily to more than one person)?

Comment: @PapaPoule. Actually, if you omit the emphatic “à toi” (which you can), the sentence would more likely be understood literally. But you're right that it is useful to form a contrast with other people in that case too.

Comment: @Ced I do not pretend being able to write correct English, but what is wrong with my translation attempt ? I have found *I have seen some of those. Somebody showed some of them to me recently, and I don't know where they came from.* The Legion Companion, Glen Cadigan

Comment: The part "*showed some of them to you too*" is super far from the original french sentence and meaning that the OP gave us. "**Alina t’en a fait voir à toi aussi**" could only be translated to "**Alina gave you a hard time too**"

Comment: @Ced Même si ce n'est sûrement pas celui attendu par la question, la phrase française peut quand même avoir le sens que je défends ici, même s'il est peu courant. On peut imaginer cette phrase : *Elle m'avait montré quelques tableaux qu'elle conservait dans un coffre, on dirait qu'Alina t’en a fait voir à toi aussi*.

Comment: @jlliagre En effet j'ai bien compris, je voulais juste souligner que la traduction anglaise était mal formulée voir incorrecte tel quel, j'aurais plutôt écrit quelque chose comme "*It looks like Alina also showed you some of them.*"

Comment: @PapaPoule I think that even without *à toi*, *aussi* almost necessarily means "**also** to you/to you **too**" in *elle t'en a fait voir aussi*. Someone else (likely the speaker) had a hard time or was shown it previously.

Comment: @Ced As a native English speaker, the sentence suggested by jlliagre appears to be correct English and sounds natural to me. Your translation is also correct English and has an identical meaning to jlliagre's. Could you explain what you think is wrong with jlliagre's translation?